# How can I replace the value inside a yaml file from another yaml file in bash

Tags: bash, yaml

I would like to replace a single value inside a yaml file (file1.yml) with the value of another yaml file (file2.yml). The key inside both file:

```
app:
  key: 12345
```

So far here is what I have done using sed with no success:

```
#!/bin/bash

old_value=`cat file1.yml | grep key | head -n1 | cut -f 2 -d ':'`
new_value=`cat file2.yml | grep key | head -n1 | cut -f 2 -d ':'`

sed "s/$old_value/$new_value/g;" file1.yml
```

I guess I should not be sending the standard output with sed and should be using awk.

Comment: Ideally, you'd use a tool that parses YAML, such as [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), is that an option?

Comment: Also, when you way "with no success", what does that mean? What happens?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sed fails with "unknown option to `s'" error. Unfortunately I cannot install any additional package on the machine on which the script will run.

Answer (score 2):

To manipulate `yaml` files, you should employ a `yaml` processor, like [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) or [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq).

Using `mikefarah/yq`:

```sh
new="$(yq '.key' file2.yml)" yq -i '.key = env(new)' file1.yml
```

Using `kislyuk/yq`:

```sh
yml="$(yq -y -s '.[0].key = .[1].key | .[0]' file1.yml file2.yml)"
cat <<< "$yml" > file1.yml
```

Answer (score 1):

Because in a yaml file the same value may exist in multiple places you want to use sed to perform a full search and then replace the value you are looking for; or use an specialized tool like [yq (a jq wrapper)](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/)

For example, this yaml file is valid

```yaml
app1:
  key: "1234"

app2:
  key: "1234"
```

with sed you will run the following to change `key: "1234"` to `key: "5678"` in just app2

```
sed '/^app2:/{n;s/key:.*/key: "5678"/;}' file.yaml
```

But doing the same using yq using in-place edit would look like:

```
 yq -i -y '.app2.key = "5678"' file.yml
```

Comment: Thank you but ideally I would like to be able to pass a variable containing the value of the key as it may differ from one file to another.

Comment: what is `-y` ? can't see it from yq --help from my macbook